# How to reference to the longest vector without copy it from inputs C++?

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Suppose I have a C++ function like the following:

```
int foo (vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2){

    vector<int> long_vec;
    if ( v1.size() >= v2.size())
        long_vec = v1;
    else
        long_vec = v2;

    // do stuff with "long_vec" ...
}
```

I don't want to copy the contents in "v1" or "v2" into "long_vec". Instead, I just want to know whichever "v1" or "v2" is longer, and use it. I know something like the vector reference like the following:

```
vector<int>& long_ref = v1;
```

But this reference has to be initialized when declared. Basically I want the following behavior:

```
int foo (vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2){

    //vector<int> long_vec;
    vector<int>& long_vec; // won't compile

    if ( v1.size() >= v2.size())
        long_vec = v1;
    else
        long_vec = v2;

    // do stuff with "long_vec" ...
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the conditional operator:

```
  vector<int> & long_vec = v1.size() > v2.size() ? v1 : v2;
```

Comment: you forgot the reference part

Comment: This is usually called not a conditional, but ternary operator.

Comment: @SergeyA Guess how the standard calls it :) Hint: It's not ternary

Comment: @Fureeish - Oops, typical copy and paste snafu.

Comment: @Rakete1111 fine, everyone knows it as a ternary operator :) But yes, my comment was not correct.

Comment: "Ternary" just means "composed of three parts". As it's the only operator that has three operand, people call it that. But really, the name has nothing to do with the operator's function. And let's consider the case where someone came up with another useful operator that required three operands.

Comment: @SergeyA And also, would it be useful if someone asked "how do I add two numbers together" to tell them to "use a binary operator"?

Comment: I learned something today. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator:

```
int foo (vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2){

    vector<int>& long_vec = v2.size() > v1.size() ? v2 : v1;

    // do stuff with "long_vec" ...
}
```

Comment: Perfection solution to my problem. Thank you very much.